# Pause/Execute one thread in a multithread program (C#)

Tags: c#, multithreading, sleep, scheduling, pause

Looking for a good design for the following problem (C#). Thanks in advance for any reply!

- Multithread program
- At least two threads
- First thread is running all the time
- Second thread needs to run from 9am - 5pm every weekday, and paused otherwise

My thoughts and things I have tried so far:

- Keep it two-thread. For the one that needs to be executed/paused at certain times, use Thread.Sleep. 
  Problem: Thread.Sleep doesn't seem to pause the thread at all. Thread keeps executing as if the Thread.Sleep were non-exist. Haven't figured out why (comments welcome). 
  If using a loop in place of Thread.Sleep, the thread won't wake up if it is left looping for too long (e.g. a whole night).
- Add a third thread with timers. This third thread evokes execution/pause for the second thread.
- Better ideas???

Comment: Do you pay the thread by the hour and just don't want to pay overtime? This seems like a design issue, if you need something to run at certain times, you should probably use a scheduler. What about holidays, leap days, etc? Things easily handled by a job scheduler... out of curiosity, what does this thread do that it only runs during business hours?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you let us know what your underlying problem is?

Comment: @RonBeyer Lol I don't pay the thread by the hour. And the second thread doesn't need to run on holidays. Correct me if I am wrong but job schedule requires making the thread into an executable, right? Not sure whether that would be applicable as thread 2 does need to constantly talk to thread 1 while it's up.

Comment: @ RonBeyer @Enigmativity Thread 1 talks to external API/monitors the market. Thread 2 makes decisions on when is the best time to sell/buy things.

Comment: @o1o1o111 - That's not your underlying issue (your Y). That's what you expect the two threads to do (your X). Can you let us know what "talks to external API/monitors the market" & "makes decisions on when is the best time to sell/buy things" means? And how they relate to each other?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following,

1) Main thread keeps checking system time every second/minute and spawns new thread(child) if its a weekday and time is 9am, then waits on a wait handle

2) The child thread then does the workload till 5pm, then signals the main thread on the wait handle before exit

3) Main thread wakes up and continues to wait for next weekday 9am

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This sounds great except for one thing... Does it mean the main thread has to have loops with intervals smaller than 1 sec/min?